# Unable to get rid of: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, resteasy

I am learning to use Spring, JPA, and Hibernate with RestEasy on Tomcat. I have tried everything including using JPA 2, but it doesn't help.

Here  is the stack trace:

```
---------- NFO: Hibernate 3.2.6 Oct 24, 2014 9:46:24 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit> INFO: hibernate.properties not
found Oct 24, 2014 9:46:24 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment
buildBytecodeProvider INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib Oct 24,
2014 9:46:24 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit> INFO: using JDK
1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling Oct 24, 2014 9:46:24 AM org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration configure INFO: HHH000204:
Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [    name: contact   ...] Oct 24, 2014
9:46:24 AM
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext
refresh WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization -
cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
resource [persistence-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SpringContextLoaderListener.java:48)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at
org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:641)
    at
org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
    at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    ... 22 more

Oct 24, 2014 9:46:24 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
initWebApplicationContext SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
resource [persistence-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SpringContextLoaderListener.java:48)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at
org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:641)
    at
org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
    at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    ... 22 more

Oct 24, 2014 9:46:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
listenerStart SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to
listener instance of class
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
resource [persistence-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SpringContextLoaderListener.java:48)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at
org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:641)
    at
org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
    at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    ... 22 more
```

---

```
<build>
    <finalName>restbase</finalName>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.Beta1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

---

---

```
/home/walker/workspace/restbase/target/classes:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/annotations-api.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/jasper-el.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/tomcat-jdbc.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/tomcat-api.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/commons-dbcp.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/catalina-ant.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/commons-pool.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/jasper.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/servlet-api.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/el-api.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/catalina-tribes.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/jsp-api.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/catalina.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/catalina-ha.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/tomcat-util.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.0.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.0.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.0.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.0.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-context-support-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/3.0.9.Final/resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/jboss/resteasy/jaxrs-api/3.0.9.Final/jaxrs-api-3.0.9.Final.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.6/httpclient-4.2.6.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.5/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.1/commons-io-2.1.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/net/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-spring/3.0.9.Final/resteasy-spring-3.0.9.Final.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jettison-provider/3.0.9.Final/resteasy-jettison-provider-3.0.9.Final.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxb-provider/3.0.9.Final/resteasy-jaxb-provider-3.0.9.Final.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.3.2/jettison-1.3.2.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.1.Final/hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.0.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.15.0-GA/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.3.1.GA/hibernate-annotations-3.3.1.GA.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org

/hibernate/hibernate/3.2.6.ga/hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/1.2.3/ehcache-1.2.3.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/asm/asm-attrs/1.5.3/asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib/2.1_3/cglib-2.1_3.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/asm/asm/1.5.3/asm-1.5.3.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.1.1/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.0.0.ga/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.0.ga.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/ejb3-persistence/1.0.1.GA/ejb3-persistence-1.0.1.GA.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.2.1.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.1.Final.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jcl/1.5.8/slf4j-jcl-1.5.8.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.8/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.21/mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.0.2.GA/hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.1/jaxb-api-2.1.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.1.3/jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/walker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: so either the JPA API jar or JPA implementation jar in the CLASSPATH is for JPA 1

Comment: Thanks Neil. But when I check resolved dependencies, there is no JPA 1,   I upgraded to hibernate-jpa-2.0-api, still the error.

Comment: Why not just print out (from your application) what is in the CLASSPATH if you're so convinced you don't have JPA API v1 or a JPA impl for JPA v1? That error message doesn't appear for no reason

Comment: Thanks Neil, appreciate your help. I just added pom dependencies here.

Comment: Try `mvn dependency:tree` to see also the transitive dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @JörnHorstmann. Just did take a look. There is dependency from hibernate-commons-annotations to persistence-api 1.

Comment: Checked but no more dependency. Still the error remains after clean install. NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMod . Could there be something more to it ?

Comment: Repeat: Why not just print out (__from your application__) what is in the CLASSPATH?

Comment: @NeilStockton. I thought you were asking for the pom file.

Comment: @NeilStockton added dependency tree if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was hibernate-annotations that was causing the problem.

I wasn't suspecting it to be the cause of the problem and thought it was required. I removed it and it was all working good.

Answer (score 0):

You have "org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:pom:3.3.2.Beta1:compile" in the classpath, and this is (seemingly) JPA 1.0 API.

Comment: again appreciate your help @NeilStockton. I have been trying everything under the sun to figure out or at least move to some different error, so I intentionally added ejb3-persistence:pom:3.3.2.Beta1 . With or without ejb3-persistence, will throw the same error.

Comment: so why not actually print out the CLASSPATH? (System.getProperty("java.class.path")) and then look through all entries at what classes are in each jar that it lists? that is a surefire way of debugging such a thing

Comment: I updated the question with print from CLASSPATH. Doesn't seem like any peristence-api 1 in my classpath. Anything else I can look into ?